# git rebase master based on timestamp

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

How do I rebase a repo with duplicate commits based on timestamp ?

Some background:
We have a dirty repo because of transferring from one git remote to another git remote and adjusting username on the new git remote endpoint. That results in double commits from "another" user, which is actually the same. The single consistency is the timestamp - so is there a way to remove the duplicates automatically ?

Comment: if the commits include the same changes then `rebase` should automatically delete them based on that.

Comment: your edit doesn't make much sense.  Did you try rebasing?  Are those commits linear or do you have a merge commit pointing to two separate paths?

Comment: I tried to rebase. I choose the first to "pick" and the following commits with the same message to "squash", but that just results in a new merge on the HEAD. What I am trying to do is to remove commits from the history. There are many but I can do this manually if that is possible - it would be nice if that can be done with the timestamp. Those commits are in a seperat path. One of our users changed the username and my fault was to pull and commit this changes from the new to the old repo. so now we have multiple paths because there exists dupplicate commits. Thank you

Comment: I would start with doing just `git rebase`, not `git rebase -i`.  You definitely don't want to squash.  Try posting a history that shows the branching too (`git log --graph`)

Comment: I understand your idea about rebasing. It's the way to go in this case. I stop here because my question is solved and further discussion would go to specific in my individual case. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26433553/git-rebase-master-based-on-timestamp#comment41512203_26433553) by [Andrew C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4021077/andrew-c), and mentioned in [`git rebase` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase):

> The commits that were previously saved into the temporary area are then reapplied to the current branch, one by one, in order.
>   **Note that any commits in `HEAD` which introduce the same textual changes as a commit in `HEAD..<upstream>` are omitted** (i.e., a patch already accepted upstream with a different commit message or timestamp will be skipped).

So a `rebase -i master`, accepting the list of commits as is, should result in only one set of commits, without duplicates.